# Problem with 2 projects in a tomcat with same class with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have two project running in a tomcat, both with springboot in both project I have one class with same name, sample

Project 1 named Fonetica

- I have one Class named FoneticaService
  Project 2 named rtdpjlite
- I have one dependency that have a class named FoneticaService

so when I try to start tomcat I got this error:

```
Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [br.com.exmart.app.Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'foneticaService' for bean class [br.com.lumera.fonetica.service.FoneticaService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [br.com.exmart.rtdpjlite.service.rest.fonetica.FoneticaService]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666) ~[spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353) ~[spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300) ~[spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_301]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'foneticaService' for bean class [br.com.lumera.fonetica.service.FoneticaService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [br.com.exmart.rtdpjlite.service.rest.fonetica.FoneticaService]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:345) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:283) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:135) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:289) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:247) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:247) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:200) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:169) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I need to change the name of class in one project or have any way to fix this without change the name?

tks